# wc_get_template_part not working with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying this simple ajax request to get data via ajax and using **`wc_get_template_part`** but it's returning the **500 server error**. it stuck **`to post_class()`** of **`content-product`** page.

```
function shop_filter(){
    if (! isset( $_POST['shop_filter_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['shop_filter_nonce'], 'shop_filter_nonce' ))
       return;
    $args=array('post_type'=>'product','order'=>'desc','posts_per_page'=>-1);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ){
        while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query();
    } 
    else
    {
        get_template_part('template-parts/content','none');
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_shop_filter','shop_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_shop_filter','shop_filter');
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello loic Thanks for the answer but i always use exit rather then die and my ajax was working fine but some how that wc get template part was not working the other day and now it seems to be working fine...dont know why it was not working..weird though..anyway its working now and thanks for the answer though...

Comment: Thanks you very much… That helps me

Answer (score 1):

> **VERY IMPORTANT: To avoid the error 500: 
>
>    always add `die();` at the end of your php function** (WordPress ajax).

Also, you should use **`wp_reset_query();`** with **`wp_reset_postdata();`** outside your if/else statement.

Here is your revisited code:

```
function shop_filter(){
    if (! isset( $_POST['shop_filter_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['shop_filter_nonce'], 'shop_filter_nonce' ))
       return;
    $args=array('post_type'=>'product','order'=>'desc','posts_per_page'=>-1);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ){
        while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile; 
    } 
    else
    {
        get_template_part('template-parts/content','none');
    }
    // Optionally (if needed).
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // To avoid error 500 (don't forget this)
    die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_shop_filter','shop_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_shop_filter','shop_filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `wp_die();` instead of just `die();`